# Spark sort causes former transformation running twice

Tags: java, apache-spark, stack-overflow, rdd

I recently found out that, if I apply a `sort()` function, the transformation in front would run twice. As shown below, `mapPartitions` runs twice. (I have checked downstream steps, it was not caused by another action to re-computing this transformation, The transformation repeat it self independently)

```java
ReflexivSubKmerDS.cache();
DSExtendReflexivKmerToArrayFirstTime DSKmerExtentionToArrayFirst = new DSExtendReflexivKmerToArrayFirstTime();
ReflexivLongSubKmerDS = ReflexivSubKmerDS.mapPartitions(DSKmerExtentionToArrayFirst, ReflexivLongSubKmerEncoderCompressed);

ReflexivLongSubKmerDS = ReflexivLongSubKmerDS.sort("k-1");
```

If I add a cache() or persist() before the sort() function, the problem goes away, it only ran once.

```
ReflexivSubKmerDS.cache();
DSExtendReflexivKmerToArrayFirstTime DSKmerExtentionToArrayFirst = new DSExtendReflexivKmerToArrayFirstTime();
ReflexivLongSubKmerDS = ReflexivSubKmerDS.mapPartitions(DSKmerExtentionToArrayFirst, ReflexivLongSubKmerEncoderCompressed);

ReflexivLongSubKmerDS.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY());
ReflexivLongSubKmerDS = ReflexivLongSubKmerDS.sort("k-1");
```

Does this make any sense? Is it normal?

Thank you

I have checked downstream steps, it was not caused by another action to re-computing this transformation, The transformation repeat it self independently

I also checked, if this is only a sampling step by `sort()` function. But apparently, all elements of the RDD was computed.

Comment: That's correct and expected: RangePartitioner is implementing reservoir sampling via the sketch method in Partitioner.scala. In order to generate a truly random sample, all elements must be read. Imagine if you had a single column of 100 integers from 1 to 100 you wanted to sort that was already sorted in ascending order, and only read the first 10% of this data. You'd only get read some of the smallest values (1-11), so your estimated "range" wouldn't be right.

Comment: Borrowed from so elsewhere.

Comment: Oh how i hate java.

Comment: @thebluephantom thank you very much for the explanation. I thought sketch is to random sample a subset of the RDD. So, I was expecting first run only iterates part of the data. But for me, the two runs both iterated through the entire RDD list.

Comment: @thebluephantom my follow up question would be. Since cache() can avoid an extra run of the transformation. Does everyone really always cache() before sort()? What if I have an iterative process of sort(). This would case stack overflow.

Comment: I was thinking of that to. Not sure.

Comment: There could be bugs in the code...